# tar wildcards in files-from

Tags: tar, wildcards

Trying to run `tar` with `--files-from`. I have a file files.txt that contains

```
/dir1/files*.txt
```

However it complains that /dir1/files*.txt does not exist, but `ls` proves that it does.

I tried to also add `--wildcards` however same result.

How do I successfully archive wildcards while using `--files-from` without specifying files on the command line?

Answer (score 5):

An asterisks in a command is expanded before running the command by a shell, such as bash.

For example, when you run `ls *.txt`, and you have three txt files in a directory named `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` bash expands it to
`ls a.txt b.txt c.txt`

I don't believe GNU tar supports this kind of behaviour, however you can use find and pipe it into tar:
`find /dir1 -iname '*.txt' -printf '%P\n' | tar --files-from=- -cvf textfiles.tar`

According to the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_50.html), the `--wildcards` flag can only be used when extracting or listing the contents of an already existing archive.

Comment: +1 for -printf '%P\n'